# Oracle Reading from json respond

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

i have the next problem. Having this query:

```
select apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
     p_url => 'https://something.com/rest/Discount'
     ,p_http_method => 'GET'
     ,p_username => 'username'
     ,p_password => 'password'
    ) as custom
from dual;
```

That return this:

```
{"hasMore":false,"items":[{"id":12,"Origin":"ALL","Part":"PO423S","Channel":"RC"},{"id":13,"Origin":"ALL","Part":"LO123D","Channel":"RC"},{"id":14,"Origin":"ALL","Part":"SD765S","Channel":"AP"}]}
```

I want to make a Channel group by to see how many Channels i have to insert into another table.

i try this just to list:

```
select d.custom.items
from  (
    select apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
        p_url =>  'https://something.com/rest/Discount'
       ,p_http_method => 'GET'
       ,p_username => 'username'
       ,p_password => 'password'
    ) as custom
    from dual) d;
```

but i have this error:

```
ORA-22806: no es un objeto ni un elemento REF
22806. 00000 -  "not an object or REF"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to extract an attribute from an item that is
           neither an object nor a REF.
*Action:   Use an object type or REF type item and retry the operation.
Error en la línea: 12, columna: 8
```

---

I also test the next:

```
create table temp_json (
  json_data blob not null
);
alter table temp_json
  add constraint temp_data_json 
  check ( json_data is json );

insert into temp_json
select apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
     p_url =>  'https://something.com/rest/Discount'
    ,p_http_method => 'GET'
    ,p_username => 'username'
    ,p_password => 'password
    ) as customDiscAplicability
from dual
;

select d.json_data.items
from   temp_json d;
```

And teh result is this:

```
ITEMS
-----
(null)
```

I follow this tutorial: [LINK](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-store-query-and-create-json-documents-in-oracle-database)

Can somebody help me ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you select `apex_web_service.make_rest_request`, it returns a string. The database doesn't know this is JSON data.

If you're on Oracle Database 18c or higher, you should be able to get around this by using `treat ... as json`:

```
select d.custom.items.id from (
select treat ( '{
  "hasMore": false,
  "items": [  {
      "id": 12,
      "Origin": "ALL",
      "Part": "PO423S",
      "Channel": "RC"
    },  {
      "id": 13,
      "Origin": "ALL",
      "Part": "LO123D",
      "Channel": "RC"
    },  {
      "id": 14,
      "Origin": "ALL",
      "Part": "SD765S",
      "Channel": "AP"
    }
  ]
}' as json ) custom from dual
) d;

ITEMS        
[12,13,14]
```

To understand why inserting the response into the table, then selecting it returns null, we'd need to see the exact JSON that's in there!

Comment: Hello Chris, well i modify :
select d.custom.items.id from( select treat(apex_web_service.make_rest_request( p_url => 'https://something.com/rest/Discount' ,p_http_method => 'GET' ,p_username => 'username' ,p_password => 'password') as json) custom from dual ) d;
/* And see the same error --> ORA-22806: no es un objeto ni un elemento REF
22806. 00000 -  "not an object or REF" */

Comment: Hello Chris, another think , if i execute your query, y receive the same error. I'm using Oracle Autonomous Database version 19.
Error: ORA-22806: no es un objeto ni un elemento REF
22806. 00000 -  "not an object or REF"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to extract an attribute from an item that is
           neither an object nor a REF.
*Action:   Use an object type or REF type item and retry the operation.
Error en la línea: 1, columna: 8

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure what's going on here. The example works fine for me on ATP 19c. You may need to contact support